# Android filter files from file explorer

Tags: java, android, file, browser, zip

Hi i'm working on a simple file browser for part of an app i'm writing but what i would like to do is if the file ends with .zip in the onclick i would like to do something else than any other file here's my class so far and thank you for any help

```
public class Installed extends ListActivity {

 private List<String> item = null;
 private List<String> path = null;
 private String root= "/";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.installed);
        getDir(root);
    }

    private void getDir(String dirPath)
    {

     item = new ArrayList<String>();
     path = new ArrayList<String>();

     File f = new File(dirPath);
     File[] files = f.listFiles();

     if(!dirPath.equals(root))
     {

      item.add(root);
      path.add(root);

      item.add("../");
      path.add(f.getParent());

     }

     for(int i=0; i < files.length; i++)
     {
       File file = files[i];
       path.add(file.getPath());
       if(file.isDirectory())
        item.add(file.getName() + "/");
       else
        item.add(file.getName());
     }

     ArrayAdapter<String> fileList =
      new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, item);
     setListAdapter(fileList);
    }

 @Override
 protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

  File file = new File(path.get(position));

  if (file.isDirectory())
  {
   if(file.canRead())
    getDir(path.get(position));
   else
   {
       Toast.makeText(Installed.this, file.getName() + " can't be read!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
  }
  else
  {
   if(file.toString().endsWith(".zip")){
       Toast.makeText(Installed.this, file.getName() + " is zip", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }else{
       Toast.makeText(Installed.this, file.getName() + " isn't zip", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: figured it out not even ten seconds later i wasn't doing toString i just did endsWith which errored for me sorry about that editing the op

Comment: Yea but thanks for the answer was going to post my own answer but i'll give you the check thanks for the help anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check if the file name ends with the ZIP extensions if you can rely on the file name, else you can check for the magic code. For the zip file it should be  "PK" (0x50 4B)

```
//--snip 
else
  {
    if (file.getName().toUpperCase().endsWith(".ZIP")  ){
      //Do something with the zip file
    }
  }
//--snip
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
file.toString().endsWith(".zip")
```